# How to read a long from a pipe?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pipe

This concerns unnamed pipes in interprocess communication.
I have a pipe and one process stores a value in it and the other want to read this valus which is numerical, either int or long.

It is well described here http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html how to create pipes in C. My question is how to read a long or int from a pipe.

extract from above mentioned page:

```
/* Read in a string from the pipe */
int nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
```

well, in generell i have no idea how a pipe is treated in C (It is like a file?) and how i can read data other than a string from it.

Comment: On Unix, [everything is a file](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki/wiki?EverythingIsaFile).

Comment: Maybe to add: I want to send it just by printf("%d",intnum), so the child process' standardinput should be transfered to this pipe. Should I maybe add a newline symbol? like printf("%d\n",intnum) ---well it is easy to see that i didnt really understand input and output in c or c++. any advises or reading recommendations are appreciated....Also, what is the size of an int like 3867? I guess in bytes..maybe 4?

Answer (score 2):

You can't "really" read a `long` from a pipe. You read a sequence of bytes from a pipe, and if you can define some protocol for which long those bytes represent, then you've read a long.

Assuming that both ends of the pipe are using the same storage representation for `long`, which they are if they were compiled with the same compiler for the same architecture, or for that matter with different compilers but using the same ABI, then you can `write(fd, &src_long, sizeof(long));` at one end, and `read(fd, &dst_long, sizeof(long));` at the other end. Plus or minus the usual messing about to ensure the I/O didn't finish early.

Comment: You may want to add that you can use [`fdopen(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) to open a pipe as a stdio file, which can then be used with `fscanf` to read data as text instead of binary.

Comment: Adam: well, you've added it. Agreed, ASCII is also a good choice of representation.

Answer (score 1):

A pipe is just like a file, except it is unseekable. When you read data, it is "gone" from the pipe and can't be read again.

You would read a datastructure like you would from any other file. It can be done with scanf, fstream>> or with a read() and a union.

Answer (score 1):

Since both ends of your pipe are on the same machine, you don't have to worry about differences in machine architectures; if you changed the question to discuss sockets, you would have to worry about that.

You can write a long to the pipe using:

```
long l = 0x01020304L
if (write(pipe_w_fd, &l, sizeof(l)) != sizeof(l))
    ...handle error...
```

And you can read the value off the pipe using:

```
long l;
if (read(pipe_r_fd, &l, sizeof(l)) != sizeof(l))
    ...handle error...
```

If you had to deal with different machine architectures, you'd format the value into a platform-neutral format (e.g. big-endian) and write that on one end, and read the platform-neutral data on the other end and convert back to the local machine-specific format.

Comment: looks fine, except that i really have to use standard input like printf for the write (the called process from the child process doesn't know about the pipe but can inherit standard input, that's at least described in the given website). but i can try it like this

Comment: @coooop: use `frwrite()` and `fread()` then with appropriate arguments, and remember to flush when appropriate too.  Messages that fit in the pipe buffer (sometimes as small as 4096, but that's way bigger than the size of a long) are maintained as atomic data (unless you only try to read part of a message).  This helps considerably.  You might also need to use `fdopen()` on the writing side to create the output file stream, and maybe `freopen()` too if it must be standard output.

Comment: Disagree with your assumption about "both ends of the pipe".  What if the compiler is different?  What if the other end of the pipe ends up doing an `exec` of a binary that gets run in some kind of emulation mode?  What if it does an `exec` that leads to an `ssh` command or similar?  Lastly, even if you think you can answer "it won't happen" to these questions...  Why not make these scenarios possible anyway?  It's not a lot of extra effort, and it's better to write code that can be re-purposed.

Comment: @asveikau: I mentioned the issue - some other answers don't even mention it.  It is hard to tell what is expected of a homework question like this.  I think it is usually better to give accurate information that meets the immediate requirements, leaving pointers to where extra work might be needed in 'commercial grade' programming.  At this stage, though, it would probably overwhelm the O/P with too much detail.

Comment: Note that with the prevalence of 32 bit x86 binaries running on 64 bit x86-64 OSes (and similar for SPARC on SPARC64), being on the same machine isn't the guarantee that it once was.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how it's sent. If you have some protocol / framing convention, you'll have to read the frame and then extract the int. If you're sending just the int itself, you can read sizeof(int) bytes and then use the bytes in the buffer directly:

```
int foo = *((int*) readbuffer);
```

Since the pipe is local, you won't have to (in most cases) care about endianness and sizes here.

Comment: ah thanks. but another thing: what is the size of an int like 3867`

Comment: An `int` always has the size `sizeof(int)`. The value does not matter.

Comment: Your example `*((int*) readbuffer)` will crash on platforms which require aligned access to integers. If you're going to store `int`s you might as well declare `readbuffer` to be an array of `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

> well, in generell i have no idea how a pipe is treated in C (It is like a file?)

Yes.

> and how i can read data other than a string from it.

This is the naive case, which assumes the long is binary and the same size in the system. If the long was written as a string, read a string then find the long.

```
long mylong;
int nbytes = read(fd[0], &mylong, sizeof(long));
```

Comment: is binary? define binary (big endian, little endian etc)

Comment: assume it is the same size? how could it differ?

Answer (score 0):

It is treated like a file. I would read up on scanf to see what data you can easily parse. Things like integers, and integers in hex or oct can be easily parsed, even pointers can be parsed. Longs are not as simple, but you can just parse a long from a string (%s) and store it in a long later.

http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html

Comment: Pointers can be parsed, but unless you're using shared memory, you should not be sending pointers across pipes!  The value of a pointer in one process is completely meaningless to any other process due to virtual memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
long l;

if (read(fd[0], &l, sizeof(l)) != sizeof(l))
{
   /* TODO: handle this */
}
```

By having your serialization type be `long` you lose some flexibility here, as it may be possible that whoever is reading this data ends up with different byte order or a different size for `long`.  Imagine, as an example, that you `fork` and `dup2(fd[1], 1)` t
hen end up `exec`-ing an SSH command in the child process...  Now the data potentially comes from another machine, and there will be problems.  To avoid it you can do something like this:

```
/* Type of l has a predictable size. */
uint32_t l;

if (read(fd[0], &l, sizeof(l)) != sizeof(l))
{
   /* TODO: handle this */
}

/* Convert byte order of what we just read */
l = ntohl(l);
```

In actuality it's a little strange to `read` in 32-bit increments...  What you should consider is to come up with a message format and read larger chunks of data at a time.  A good way to accomplish this is for each quantity of information to have a header that indicates the size of what follows, message type, etc.  Or if you don't find this appealing you can consider having your serialization be text.  This would also provide a decent answer to the endianness problem.